# No maxlen option to limit stream size in spring data reactive Redis Template

Tags: spring, redis, spring-webflux, spring-data-redis

I am trying out spring data redis using reactive Redis template. However, i had no success so far in finding the `Xargs` for limiting the size of the stream.

Base lettuce implementation has that option in native implementation:

```
commands
    .xadd(streamKey, XAddArgs.Builder.maxlen(200L), eventKey,
        record);
```

However, this option is unavailable in `RedisTemplate` AFAIK. The `maxlen` option is inevitable as the stream might grow exponentially.

If someone has encountered it, can you point me to the right place?

Thanks all.

Comment: I couldn't find it, consider pipelining add() with trim() to get the same effect

Comment: ahh, wasnt aware there is a trim function.. will try and post the feedback.

Comment: That will be like a 2 operations every single time we add elements to the stream then. What do you think? @LeoMurillo?

Comment: Yeah, but XTRIM is expensive. Both commands pipelined compared to XADD with MAXLEN should be negligible.

Comment: @LeoMurillo thanks for pointing that out. Firstly, i am assuming you are talking about `transaction` when you say `pipelined`. If that's the case, its a bit of a problem for me as I am working on cluster, and its usually not recommended to run transactions due to topology issues. Having said that, I did search different ways of piping and couldnt find a specific way to `pipe` or `chain` `trim()` to `add()`. Can you point out an example?

Comment: pipelined is not a transaction. See link below. We are talking about a one-key operation here so no issues at all with clusters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no support for [`XADD`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/current/reference/html/#pipeline) with `MAXLEN` in the `[StreamOperations][1]` interface of RedisTemplate.

You can [pipeline](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/current/reference/html/#pipeline) the `add(...)` with `trim(K key, long count)` ([`XTRIM`](https://redis.io/commands/xtrim)) to get a similar effect. The two commands would be sent simultaneously, so you only have one Round Trip Time.

`XTRIM` is an expensive operation compared to `XADD`. Consider trimming every now and then on a separate logic instead of with every `XADD`.

Sadly, the `MAXLEN ~` doesn't seem to be supported either, so we are left with exact count trimming only on RedisTemplate.

Comment: Thanks a lot @LeoMurillo! That helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is a good option, for me I use this way to limit the size of stream instead of using xadd cause redisTemplate doesn't support xadd

First, I trim the stream to remove and limit my size. At below, i use 1000 entries

```
redisTemplate.opsForStream().trim("Stream Key",1000);
```

Then, I add the next data like normal

```
redisTemplate.opsForStream().add(...)
```

So my data in the stream is always around 1000 entries